# Where is my /etc/init.d/skeleton on OpenSuse 12.3?

Tags: opensuse, systemd, daemon, init.d

On a fresh install of OpenSuse 12.3, I want to "daemonize" a program. And, on all examples found on Internet, I see I have to create first a `/etc/init.d/myscript` based on the `/etc/init.d/skeleton`...

But I have no `/etc/init.d/skeleton`... Is there another place for this file? Or maybe I need to install something?

The system is up-to-date, I checked that first.

I know I can try to copy another existing `/etc/init.d` script and modify it, or create a new one, but I would know if I am doing wrong, or if there is another special way to do that on OpenSuse.

Comment: As dsmsk80 points out, the examples you found are for SysV init, which is on it's way to depreciation (but since it has been around longer than the internet, it has gotten lots of write-up over the years).  OpenSUSE uses a new-fangled replacement, `systemd`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where  the `/etc/init.d/skeleton` file disappeared but I would expect that this change is related to replacement of traditional `SysV init daemon` with `systemd` since OpenSUSE 12. `systemd` is fully compatible with well knows initscripts but I would prefer to use the `systemd` model of starting services.

In my opinion, traditional initscripts can be tricky and sometimes, they may require deeper knowledge of shell scripting. On the other hand, `systemd` "initscript" or `unit` configuration file for a service (`man systemd.unit`) is easier to maintain as it has simple syntax similar to `.INI` files. You may try to write some unit file and enable it by dropping the file to the `/etc/systemd/system` directory. This directory has higher precedence than the default directory `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. An example of `sshd` daemon unit follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH Daemon
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd-gen-keys-start
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Or you may stick with "legacy" initscripts  as you are used. But you will loose some neat features of `systemd` like:

- faster boot time, real parallel startup of services
- automatic dependency handling
- moitoring of services and their automatic restart of crashed ones
- and much more

Finally, keep in mind that if there is a unit (`sshd.service`) with the same basename as an initscript (`/etc/init.d/sshd`), then, the initscript is ignored and the `systemd` unit will be preffered and used.